# Nexus 7 Sleep timelimited to 10 minutes?

Tags: nexus-7

I just purchased a Nexus 7, and wanted to set it to sleep after 15 or 20 minutes of inactivity.

I don't have this option, as the most I can set is 10 minutes.

When I search about this everything seems to indicate I should have the option up to 30 minutes.

I am on 4.4.4

Am I missing an option or was it removed? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you can set before the screen locks can be limited by a device policy, just like how a policy can enforce a particular security level for the screen lock (e.g. you must use a password). You might have a device policy if you use a corporate VPN or an Exchange account.

In this case, to increase the timeout or disable the lock screen completely, you'll have to ask your corporate IT to remove the policy, which will also remove your access to the work resources (VPN or Exchange server).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Is it possible to use another program with device administrator privs to override that?

Comment: It would defeat the object if you could.

Comment: Well I'm not meant to be rooted, but a hidemyroot app takes care of that. Thought there might be a similar way to get around this issue.